# my bluetooth handset has been paired with my laptop but its showing disconnected in sound playback option

Tags: bluetooth, connectivity, handset

image is here [image]

also i check for different answers and did some troubleshooting but it didn't helped, i check for services it sometimes shows me services and some times not, when it shows services like listen to music and some other but it can not be selected means to say that its just a dummy link cannot be clicked. image is here
[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI: This site is for programming questions, not hardware/software configuration problems (unless the problem is specifically programming related, like configuring an IDE or interpreter/compiler). Your question will probably be moved to Superuser.

Comment: thanks for ur comment @FredrickBrennan i checked superUser for the answer, it has a same related question but i didnt helped me and my problem remains the same i didnt knew that its just for programming only so posted here